# Console global scope variable of same name inside local scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

I want to print the global scope variable declared using let which is also declared with same name inside a function.

I have used window object but it kept on saying window is not defined.

```js
var globalLet = "This is a global variable";
 
function fun() {
  var globalLet = "This is a local variable";
  console.log(globalLet); //want to print 'This is global variable' here.
}
fun();
```

Comment: can you give the full error you are getting

Comment: What do you mean by _"I have used window object"_? What does that code look like? Are you running this in a browser or via something like Node.js?

Comment: https://repl.it/@MukulLatiyan/javascript visit this link and try running it.

Comment: @Phil via Node.

Comment: Window object is provided by the browser, node does not have it

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.varname` to access the global variable

```js
var globalLet = "This is a global variable";

function fun() {
  var globalLet = "This is a local variable";
  console.log(this.globalLet); //want to print 'This is global variable' here.
}
fun();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the value of `this` to `null` then it will always map to the global object (in non-strict mode).

Here just declaring an anonymous function and setting `this` as null and calling it immediately by passing the property of the global object `globalLet` will always return the global value.

**Caution**: This won't work in strict mode, where `this` will point to `null`.

```js
var globalLet = "This is a global variable";
 
function fun() {
  var globalLet = "This is a local variable";
  globalLet = (function(name){return this[name]}).call(null, "globalLet");
  console.log(globalLet); //want to print 'This is global variable' here.
}
fun();
```

According to the [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4)

> 15.3.4.4 Function.prototype.call (thisArg [ , arg1 [ , arg2, … ] ] ) # Ⓣ Ⓡ When the call method is called on an object func with argument
>   thisArg and optional arguments arg1, arg2 etc, the following steps are
>   taken:
>
> If IsCallable(func) is false, then throw a TypeError exception.
>
> Let argList be an empty List.
>
> If this method was called with more than one argument then in left to
>   right order starting with arg1 append each argument as the last
>   element of argList
>
> Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of func,
>   providing thisArg as the this value and argList as the list of
>   arguments.
>
> The length property of the call method is 1.
>
> NOTE The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this
>   value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a undefined or null
>   thisArg is replaced with the global object and ToObject is applied to
>   all other values and that result is passed as the this value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` keyword in global context, it is bound to global object.

```js
var globalLet = "This is a global variable";
 
function fun() {
  var globalLet = "This is a local variable";
  console.log(this.globalLet); //want to print 'This is global variable' here.
}
fun();
```